# node.js split received string into different variables, then format as a json string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a udp script from http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-udp-server-and-client-example.html which I want to modify so that the string it receives 'filename lat lon' is split into separate variables 'filename' 'lat' and 'lon', respectively, and then formatted as a json string.

i.e.

```
{
    "name" : "filename",
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ lat, lon ]
}
```

this is the script I'm using to receive the string:

```js
var PORT = 33333; 
var HOST = '127.0.0.1'; 
var dgram = require('dgram'); 
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4'); 
server.on('listening', function () { 
    var address = server.address(); 
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port); 
}); 
server.on('message', function (message, remote) { 
    console.log('' + message); 
}); 
server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

an example of the string would be '1491.wav -78.2371 43.8019'

Thank you!

Comment: what is the content of a, b, c?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? There's no better way to learn than to read [good reference material](https://developer.mozilla.org) and work through tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please show us what you have tried so far, and we will help you debug the issues.

Comment: you should update your question with this info.

Comment: ok thank you will do

Comment: @MichaelPalumbo: The code you've quoted above has nothing whatsoever to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume `a` should have the file name and `b` and `c` the coords.

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to identify the parts of the string you want, using capture groups to capture the text in those parts, and then create an object (not JSON) with the result. If you want JSON (**text**, a *string*), you can then convert the object to JSON via `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var str = "000001.wav -73.778889 40.639722";
var parts = /^\s*([^ ]+) +([-\d.]+) +([-\d.]+)\s*$/.exec(str);
if (!parts || isNaN(parts[2]) || isNaN(parts[3])) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Invalid string";
} else {
  // String was as expected
  var obj = {
    name: parts[1],
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
      +parts[2],
      +parts[3]
    ]
  };
  document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

Here's that regex explained (also [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pI0eZ8/1)):

- `^` - Start of input
- `\s*` - Zero or more whitespace characters
- `([^ ]+)` - One or more characters that are not spaces, wrapped in a capture group (`(...)`) so we can get the matching text later
- `+` - One or more spaces
- `([-\d.]+)` - One or more of the characters `-`, `.`, or any digit (this isn't as restrictive as it could be, but...); capture it, this is the first coord
- `+` - One or more spaces
- ([-\d.]+)` - The second coord, captured
- `\s*` - Zero or more whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string

`RegExp#exec` returns an array if the string matches, with the 0th element being the full string, and then the capture groups in order.

The code above uses `+parts[2]` and `+parts[3]` to convert the string containing a coordinate into a number.

It also uses `isNaN` to check first that the string can be coerced to a number correctly.

Comment: Thank you T.J.! I forgot about regexp. I admit I'm not sure where to place this in my script so that it formats the incoming string